# Get first n elements of a list

Tags: list

How can I get the first N elements of a list?

I know I can use [`subseq`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Sequence-Functions.html):

```lisp
(subseq '("one" "two" "three" "four" "five") 0 2)
```

Yet when I use [`subseq`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Sequence-Functions.html), it produces one of the following results:

- on the first call, the message `"function 'subseq' from cl package called at runtime"` or,
- an error that `"progn: Symbol’s function definition is void: subseq"` when using vanilla `emacs -Q`.

I could overcome these by using `(require 'cl-extras)` or `cl-subseq`.  But given these hiccups, I expect there is a more direct way to get the first *N* elements.

Looking through documentation didn't turn up anything and the implementation of `cl-subseq` is non-trivial.  If a builtin doesn't exist, I imagine to implement from scratch would require something like "Get the `car` of each `cdr`".  Yet, this makes me think of `loop`... which is also a `cl` extension.

Thoughts?

Comment: "My ultimate goal is to read the first N lines of a file" is *such* a different use-case to the question that I strongly recommend you remove that text from this question, and ask a new separate question which is "Read the first N lines of a file".

Comment: i.e. The best solution to your actual question will almost certainly be to move over N newlines and *then you're done* (more or less).  No one is likely to recommend reading the *entire file* into a list as a starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `butlast`. The following code snippet returns the first 3 elements, you can vary the number 3 in the snippet.

```
(let ((list '("one" "two" "three" "four" "five")))
  (butlast list (- (length list) 3)))
```

Comment: Or `nbutlast` to do the same thing destructively.

Answer (score 1):

I think the sensible options are:

- `(require 'cl-lib)` and use `cl-subseq`
- `(require 'seq)` and use `seq-subseq`

The latter actually uses the former, but you might prefer using the `seq` library functions generally.

You could roll your own, but I would just use one of the above.

Comment: Worth mention `seq-take` does more directly what the questioner asks.

Answer (score 1):

(Elevating ideasman42 comment to an answer)

Worth mention `seq-take` does more directly what the questioner asks.

```
(setq l1 '("one" "two" "three" "four" "five"))
(seq-take l1 3)
("one" "two" "three")
```